# Бьются ссылки сайта на wordpess при использовании LAMP и Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, apache2, lamp

- На хостинге развернул сайт на wordpess, по адресу http://test.ru
- Для дальнейшей разработки перенес сайт с хостинга себе на локальный в папку
  D:\sites\app\test.ru
- Запустил Docker командой:
  docker run -i -t -p "80:80" -v d:/sites/app:/app -v d:/sites/mysql:/var/lib/mysql mattrayner/lamp:latest-1604-php7
- Перенес БД

Всё ок, только сайт запускается по адресу
http://localhost/test.ru при этом все ссылки бьются. Нужно колдовать с БД(и не только), менять адреса, а потом при переносе на хост опять все менять. Возникли следующие вопросы:

1. Как это можно реализовать более правильно, проще и элегантнее?
2. Как сделать так чтобы сайт открывался не по http://localhost/test.ru а по http://test.ru
3. Вообще почему так происходит? Ведь сайт в docker запущен по адресу http://test.ru, и перенаправление идет на локальную машину http://localhost:80/test.ru Получается что запросы все итоговые происходят на адресе http://test.ru в докере, почему же тогда бьются ссылки?

Comment: Потому что вы не понимаете, как устроен WordPress: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220

Comment: Благодарю за статью. Есть интересные моменты, да и освежить память.  
Но вопрос был немного о другом:
Почему перенаправление с http://localhost:80/test.ru на http://test.ru в докере бьёт ссылки. Ведь сайт в контейнере работает на http://test.ru и по идее ссылки менять не нужно?

Comment: Ну либо наличие в базе путей к файлам от корня WordPress, от домашнего каталога пользователя хостинг-аккаунта или от корня веб-сервера - бьет всё. В чем я сомневаюсь...

Comment: Все ссылки внутри WordPress абсолютные. Страница генерируется для test.ru, и все ссылки на ней на test.ru. Куда вы её там переадресовываете, не имеет значения. Хотите, чтобы работало по новому адресу - меняйте ссылки в базе, как указано в моей статье.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. 1 и 3 пункты тогда отвечены и закрыты. Хотелось бы узнать как реализовать пункт 2

Comment: Прописать test.ru в hosts локального компьютера

Comment: Если я пропишу test.ru в локальном, то получается http://test.ru/test.ru

Comment: Если у вас в докере есть WP-CLI: то просто `wp search-replace 'старый домен' 'новый домен'`

Comment: Спасибо за WP-CLI, полезный инструмент